# ActionView::Template::Error (defaults.js isn't precompiled)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger

Recently, I've been working on migrating my Ruby on Rails site, built on passenger, to a different server, and in the process upgrade rails from 2.3.2 to 3.2. I've installed all necessary gems, and I thought configured everything correctly, but when I go to my site, I get a "We're sorry, but something went wrong" message

I checked the production.log and this is the error message I got:

> Connecting to database specified by database.yml
>
> Started GET "/login/login" for ip_address at 2013-05-31 20:12:28 -0400
>   Processing by LoginController#login as HTML
>
> Rendered login/login.html.erb within layouts/homepage (6.9ms)
>
> Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 43ms
>
> ActionView::Template::Error (defaults.js isn't precompiled):
>
> 6:`<title>test test test</title>`
>
> 7:    `<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/images/favicon.ico">`
>
> 8:     `<link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="/images/favicon.ico"/>`
>
> 9: `<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>`
>
> 10:   `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`
>
> 11:     `<script type="text/javascript" >src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>`
>
> 12:         `<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/jquery-ui->1.8.20.custom.min.js"></script>      <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'home_styles', :media => >'Screen' %>`
>
> app/views/layouts/homepage.html.erb:9:in
>   _app_views_layouts_homepage_html_erb__3199970246383683518_43112000'

I'm still pretty new to Rails, so I'm currently at a bit of a loss what to do. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

This tag is from Rails versions pre 3.1. Are you sure this is what you want to do?

In newer applications, this line is typically including the application JavaScript file instead:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

This is made possible due to the Asset Pipeline which you can learn about by reading [The Asset Pipeline Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

Comment: Thanks, I made the changes and everythings working now. Thanks for the help, this has been driving me crazy!

Comment: @Darendal If this answered your question then please click the green tick to accept it as the answer. Thanks!